# php json_decode function doesn't work with me

Tags: php, arrays, json

when decoding this json file 'https://2geekproar.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json&callback=showpostcount' ,  Nothing appears to me
and i want o get $totalResults":{"$t":"4"} which equals '4' i want to decode this json file and get this value

my code

```
<?php 

$url = 'https://2geekproar.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json&callback=showpostcount' ;

$json = file_get_contents($url);
    
// Decode the JSON file
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);
  

// Display data
print_r($json_data);

?>
```

Comment: The response of the URL isn't a JSON.

Comment: Remove the `callback` argument. This is JSONP.

Comment: To continue off @HoangHieu's comment, what you're getting back is JSONP. If you're passing the response at this URL to a JSON parser directly, why have you opted to include the `callback` parameter? This will cause `json_decode()` to fail as JSONP is not parseable as true JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add `echo json_last_error_msg();` to your script, you will see that you get the following error message:

```
Syntax error
```

That indicates to you, that the string you are trying to decode is not a valid JSON string.

Because of that, you are getting no output.

```php
var_dump($json_data); // Returns NULL
```

So, because the string you are parsing is not well formatted, you have to check that out, viewing the URL shows:

```js
// API callback
showpostcount({"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":
// …
```

Which indeed is not a plain JSON object.

As pointed out in the comments under your question, you can fix that, by removing `&callback=showpostcount` from your request URL.

```
https://2geekproar.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json
```

Will give you only your valid JSON object, which you can parse without problems:

```json
{"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":…
```

Decodes to:

```
array(3) {
  ["version"]=>
  string(3) "1.0"
  ["encoding"]=>
  string(5) "UTF-8"
  ["feed"]=>
  array(18) {
    ["xmlns"]=> …
```